# Find out why my action is not responsing even if it is working in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm refactoring a library where I create the fullfillment of Dialogflow v2. In Dialogflow I see the response I am expecting. The "Fulfillment status" in the "Diagnostic info" dialog just says: "Webhook execution successful".

[image: Webhook execution successful]

However in the Actions Console I only get the response that my action is not responding.

[image: Debug output]

How can I find out what is going on?

Comment: @Sairaj that tag is important

Answer (score 1):

I totally missed the small "View logs" link and I used a crazy complex way to get there, but in the end I found there my bug:

[image: Error log]

There you can see why it is crashing. That was very helpful for me. I hope that will help others too.